# Can you access the return of a stored proc using cfstoredproc, even if return is not defined as an out parameter?

Tags: stored-procedures, coldfusion

I have a stored procedure whose return I want to access, using the Coldfusion cfstoredproc tag. However, the return variable is not listed as an out param, along with the 6 "in" params. See procedure's code below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Hire_AddEVerifyEmpCloseCase]
(   
           @e_verify_id bigint
           ,@ClientSftwrVer varchar(30)=null
           ,@CaseNbr char(15)
           ,@CloseStatus varchar(50)
           ,@CurrentlyEmployed varchar(1)
           ,@submit_user_id int
           //THIS LINE IS MISSING: @EmpCloseCase_Id int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @EmpCloseCase_id int
    SET @EmpCloseCase_id=0
    
    SELECT @EmpCloseCase_id = EmpCloseCase_id FROM Appl_Hired_EVerify_EmpCloseCase WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE e_verify_id = @e_verify_id

    BEGIN TRANSACTION EmpCloseCase
    BEGIN TRY
        IF(@EmpCloseCase_id = 0) BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Appl_Hired_EVerify_EmpCloseCase(e_verify_id,ClientSftwrVer,CaseNbr,CloseStatus,CurrentlyEmployed, systemdate,submit_user_id)
            VALUES (@e_verify_id,@ClientSftwrVer,@CaseNbr,@CloseStatus,@CurrentlyEmployed,GETDATE(),@submit_user_id)
            
            SET @EmpCloseCase_id=ISNULL(SCOPE_IDENTITY(),0)
        END ELSE BEGIN
            UPDATE Appl_Hired_EVerify_EmpCloseCase
            SET ClientSftwrVer = @ClientSftwrVer,
                CaseNbr = @CaseNbr,
                CloseStatus = @CloseStatus,
                CurrentlyEmployed = @CurrentlyEmployed, 
                systemdate = GETDATE(),
                submit_user_id = @submit_user_id
            WHERE EmpCloseCase_id = @EmpCloseCase_id
        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION EmpCloseCase
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
           SET @EmpCloseCase_id=0
           ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  EmpCloseCase
    END CATCH

   RETURN @EmpCloseCase_id
END
```

Because that "OUTPUT" line is missing, it throws an error if I try to include `<cfprocparam type="out" variable="empCloseCaseId">` in my cfstoredproc. Is there any way to access/store the value of this return variable @EmpCloseCase_id, using cfstoredproc, without having to add in that missing "OUTPUT" line or otherwise change the proc's code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
RETURN @EmpCloseCase_id
```

to

```
SELECT @EmpCloseCase_id as emp_close_case_id
```

and in your `cfstoredproc` call, add

```
<cfprocresult name="foo">
```

This defines the variable `foo` as a query with a single row and a column `emp_close_case_id`.

```
<cfoutput>
    #foo.emp_close_case_id#
</cfoutput>
```

**EDIT:** No way to access that data without properly declaring the `output` variable or returning a data set with a `select` statement. SQL Server docs: [Return Data from a Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Is there any way to access it without changing any of the stored proc's code?

Comment: I think returning a result is the better option, but... since your ate using RETURN might be worth a shot to try cfstoredproc returncode=yes which populates the variable cfstoredproc.statuscode.

Comment: .. only if you really can't change the stored proc, as that is not how `return` is normally used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15